# What abilities can assist in a caster level check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The remove curse spell requires a caster level check (d20 + caster level) vs. the curse DC.

This doesn't give fantastic odds of the spell working successfully, although I can't see any text that says you can't retry.

Given this isn't a skill check, or indeed any sort of stat check what spells/abilities can be used to give a bonus to this roll to improve chances of success?

This would be for a wizard, level 7. Little cash available but a city where hires can be done nearby. Any bonus that improves the roll is good. Have a friendly druid and paladin in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a cheaper way, I have discovered.

[Power Components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances) from [Adventurers Armoury](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Adventurer%27s_Armory) provides cheap ways to one-shot buff certain spells.

Specifically for dispelling two are particularly useful:

[Cold Iron](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances#TOC-Brimstone-Sulfur)  (5 gp for a dose of 5)  Spells of the abjuration school are cast at +1 caster level for the purpose of caster level and dispel checks

[Myrhh](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances#TOC-Myrrh)  (2 gp for a dose of 4)  Spells of the abjuration school are cast at +1 caster level for the purpose of caster level checks and dispel checks.

Not sure if they'll stack together (the bonuses appear untyped) but anyway, it's a much cheaper way to get a bonus to a caster level check.

Answer (score 9):

There are few bonuses, but the best way to effectively get a decent bonus is to use a power where you can get a reroll.  In our current Carrion Crown campaign, I run a witch with the Fortune hex (allows you to roll 2d20 and take best), and that's our go-to when we have Dispel checks, SR checks, etc. that people don't customarily have a lot of bonuses in. Of course, witch hexes aren't the only thing that gives this.  Clerics with the [Luck domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/luck-domain), a [luck blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/luck-blade), spells like [borrow fortune](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/borrow-fortune), Hero points - anything that'll let you reroll "any d20 roll."

There are some other magic items like the [orange prism ioun stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone) or a bead of karma from a [strand of prayer beads](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/beads-prayer-strand), but that's well out of your budget.

See [How much is a Second roll worth in Modifier Bonus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34688/how-much-is-a-second-roll-worth-in-modifier-bonus) for how many "points of bonus" a reroll is worth. There's math. "+5, more or less."

Comment: If you want to add it, the foresight Arcane school also has a +2 to Caster level tests option: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/divination/foresight

Answer (score 6):

## Increasing Arcane Caster Level on the Cheap Is Hard

A *wand of remove curse* [abjur] (3rd-level spell at caster level 20) costs 900 gp per charge; if used wands are available this is the easiest way to get access to a high-caster-level *remove curse* spell. Even the paladin can use the purchased *wand* (and laugh at the druid while he does).

A 5th-level or higher cleric or witch may be willing to cast the 3rd-level spell [*sharesister*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sharesister) [necro] on the wizard to grant the wizard a +1 insight bonus to caster level.

If the wizard has ranks in the skill Use Magic Device and can get a *scroll of [death knell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/death-knell)* [necro], convince the druid the chicken deserves it, stab a chicken until it's dying but not dead, and--before the chicken bleeds out--successfully cast the spell *death knell* on the chicken, the wizard can get a +1 bonus to his caster level. Yeah, I *know.*

Otherwise, a wizard's stuck with very expensive options like the [*ioun stone* (orange prism)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone).

Answer (score 4):

I googled a bit, and I found [this post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2nvb9?Raising-Caster-Level-check) on the paizo message boards.

The list is not very long however, and much is tied to class features, but you can always hire someone.

From what I've seen, the [Magician Bard Archetype's](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo---bard-archetypes/magician) Dweomercraft performance is a good way.

> *Dweomercraft (Su)*: A magician can use performance to manipulate magical energies. Allies of the magician gain a +1 bonus on caster level checks, concentration checks, and attack rolls with spells and spell-like abilities. This bonus increases by +1 at 5th level and every six levels thereafter. This ability relies on visual and audible components.

Convince your GM to place a magician in town, and hire that guy. Level 1 Bards are a cheap +1, level 5 Bard would even be +2, for a bit more cash. As far as I know, there is no official price list for class feature services, but you can orient yourself on spellcasting prices. Maybe 25xLevelxRounds in gold or similar. Note that you only need a single round of singing.

Alternatively, if you can find a cleric with the [Arcane subdomain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/magic-domain/arcane): The Arcane Beacon domain power works as well, if you cast remove curse as an arcane spell.

> *Arcane Beacon (Su)*: As a standard action you can become a beacon of arcane energy until the end of your next turn. The aura emanates 15 feet from you. All arcane spells cast within the aura either gain a +1 bonus to their caster level or increase their saving throw DC by +1. The caster chooses the benefit when she casts the spell. You can use this ability for a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Wisdom modifier.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting feat tree in the *Pathfinder Player Companion: Faiths & Philosophies* that starts with the following feat:

[**Meditation Master**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/meditation-master) allows you to, after meditating for one hour, add a +1 insight bonus to ***any d20 roll*** within 24 hours of the meditation. It has no pre-requisites.

Another feat in the same tree ([**Combat Meditation**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-meditation-combat)) is worth mentioning because it speeds up the meditation from one hour to one full-round action. Much more useful in a fight. It also lets you trade your +1 bonus for a re-roll of any ability check, attack, save, or skill check*.

Some feats in the rest of the tree are relevant for casters as well, but mostly target Concentration checks.

---

If your character is **Human**, there is also the [**Inexplicable Luck**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/inexplicable-luck-human) feat. which adds a **+8 to any d20 roll** once per day as a free action.

---

*: Doesn't include Concentration checks or Caster Level checks

Comment: Of all the options; this is about the only one my Wizard is actually going to be able to use; the other options are interesting, but the resources/clergy/etc aren't actually there!