# Do antimagic fields nullify cursed items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, curses, antimagic-field

Does an [antimagic field](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antimagic-field) nullify a [cursed item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items)? If it does nullify it can you take that item off?

Answer (score 12):

### Yes.

The *antimagic field* spell "suppresses any spell or magical effect used within, brought into, or cast into the area".  Also, "a magic sword does not function magically within the area".  Since curses are magical in nature, they are supressed when brought within the confines of the field.  Thus, you can take off cursed magic items by walking into an *antimagic field*.

As a note of comparison, *[remove curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-curse)*, the normal way of removing cursed items, is only 3rd level, while *antimagic field* is 6th, so this isn't even a stretch power-wise.

Comment: Ok cuz my DM has been saying break enchantment or remove curse wouldn't work figured cuz the dc is too high for our npcs or he just spites me

Comment: @Eric [O, in that case, try here.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36764/8610)